# Difference between the code generated from DbContext Generator for EF 5.x and EF 6.x DbContextGenerator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t4, edmx, edmx-designer

As I am using EF6 in my project and I have generated my edmx using VS2012 which uses by default "EF 5.x DbContext Generator" for generating edmx and all related code.due to which my edmx and all related code is for EF 5.0. So Can any one tell me what will be difference I will get in .tt and context.tt code files of edmx when I will generate my edmx from  EF 6.x DbContextGenerator instead of EF 5.x DbContext Generator.
I also have used EF 6.x DbContextGenerator and did not notice any change in edmx and related its code.

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the most noticeable difference in generated code is the change of namespaces, for example:

```
System.Data.Entity -> System.Data.Entity.Core
System.Data.Objects -> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying but where this change will reflect, only in context.tt file right?.  And can you tell me what is the use of context.tt file.